# Datadog Grok parser can not parse json

Tags: datadog, grok

I'm writing Grok parsing rules to extract attributes from logs, but I don't know why Grok can not extract json in some cases.

Here is the sample log:

```
[32minfo: {"status":"200 OK","time":"731.909 ms","size":"847 B","method":"POST","url":"/graphql"} {"context":"Response","service":"my-service","timestamp":"2023-12-09T09:06:43+00:00"}[39m
```

The parsing rules:

```
api_parsing_rule \[%{integer}m%{notSpace:level}: (%{regex("[^{]*"):message}|%{data:data:json}) %{data:meta:json}
```

Extraction:

```
{
  "level": "info"
}
```

When I delete **status**, **time**, **size** fields from the json, it works:
New sample log:

```
[32minfo: {"method":"POST","url":"/graphql"} {"context":"Response","service":"my-service","timestamp":"2023-12-09T09:06:43+00:00"}[39m
```

New extraction:

```
{
  "data": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/graphql"
  },
  "level": "info",
  "meta": {
    "service": "my-service",
    "context": "Response",
    "timestamp": "2023-12-09T09:06:43+00:00"
  }
}
```

Do you know why? Thanks!